# Saltstack grains error in template file

Tags: saltstack

Using {{ grains['host'] }} in a managed file returns the following error:

```
 Function: file.managed
      Result: False
     Comment: Unable to manage file: Jinja variable dict object has no element Undefined; line 54

              name = {{ grains['host'] }}    <======================
```

Sls:

```
/usr/file.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://file.jinja
    - template: jinja
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
```

I have grains working fine elsewhere. Any thoughts?

Answer (score -2):

Clearing the mine data has fixed this problem:

```
salt '*' mine.flush
```

Comment: That command doesn't make sense to fix grains issues. Probably you had wrong hostname or a wrong /etc/hosts file.